# Why heap area not shown in case of large memory allocation?

Tags: c, memory-management, operating-system, malloc

After allocating large memory area using malloc, I am trying to check the span of heap area in **/proc/[pid]/maps** file. Below is the code that I wrote.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                              
#include <stdlib.h>                                                             
#include <unistd.h>                                                             

int main()                                                                      
{                                                                               
  void *p = malloc(1024LL * 1024LL * 1024LL * 4);                                                    

  if (p == NULL)                                                                
  {                                                                             
    printf("alloc fail\n");                                                     
  }
  //else                                                                        
  //{                                                                           
     //printf("memory allocated at %p\n", p);                                    
  //}                                                                             

  while (1) sleep(1);                                                           
  free(p);                                                                      
  return 0;                                                                     
}
```

When I check **/proc/[pid]/maps** file, there is no mapping shown for the heap area.

```
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 20185722                           /home/soumen/a.out
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:01 20185722                           /home/soumen/a.out
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 20185722                           /home/soumen/a.out
7f19f98df000-7f1af98e0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1af98e0000-7f1af9a9f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 23462292                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f1af9a9f000-7f1af9c9f000 ---p 001bf000 08:01 23462292                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f1af9c9f000-7f1af9ca3000 r--p 001bf000 08:01 23462292                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f1af9ca3000-7f1af9ca5000 rw-p 001c3000 08:01 23462292                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f1af9ca5000-7f1af9ca9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1af9ca9000-7f1af9ccf000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 23462295                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f1af9ea4000-7f1af9ea7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1af9ecc000-7f1af9ece000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1af9ece000-7f1af9ecf000 r--p 00025000 08:01 23462295                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f1af9ecf000-7f1af9ed0000 rw-p 00026000 08:01 23462295                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f1af9ed0000-7f1af9ed1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffe71fe1000-7ffe72002000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffe72094000-7ffe72096000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffe72096000-7ffe72098000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Now I **uncomment the else section** in the code and run it again. This time the heap area appears in **/proc/[pid]/maps** file. But it is much smaller than what is being allocated.

Also, the starting address of the allocated region does not fall inside the heap area limit shown in **/proc/[pid]/maps** file.

Program output:

```
memory allocated at 0x7fcab87e2010
```

Contents of **/proc/[pid]/maps** file

```
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 20185722                           /home/soumen/a.out
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:01 20185722                           /home/soumen/a.out
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 20185722                           /home/soumen/a.out
00bba000-00bdb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fcab87e2000-7fcbb87e3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcbb87e3000-7fcbb89a2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 23462292                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fcbb89a2000-7fcbb8ba2000 ---p 001bf000 08:01 23462292                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fcbb8ba2000-7fcbb8ba6000 r--p 001bf000 08:01 23462292                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fcbb8ba6000-7fcbb8ba8000 rw-p 001c3000 08:01 23462292                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fcbb8ba8000-7fcbb8bac000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcbb8bac000-7fcbb8bd2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 23462295                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fcbb8da7000-7fcbb8daa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcbb8dcf000-7fcbb8dd1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcbb8dd1000-7fcbb8dd2000 r--p 00025000 08:01 23462295                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fcbb8dd2000-7fcbb8dd3000 rw-p 00026000 08:01 23462295                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7fcbb8dd3000-7fcbb8dd4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff2df8f000-7fff2dfb0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff2dfec000-7fff2dfee000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fff2dfee000-7fff2dff0000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

So what is being done here by the OS? Can malloc call defer memory allocation until it is being referred to?

Configuration I am using

1. Linux nightfury 4.4.0-78-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 27 15:29:09 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
2. gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: Are you sure the allocation and free are not optimized out? I'd do that if I was a compiler. :)

Comment: Memory manager could allocate memory on the first use. Try adding `memset` call to your code.

Comment: large allocations are served by glibc's `malloc` directly through `mmap`, this might be the explanation (and the heap you see is maybe somehow used by `printf`)

Comment: @FelixPalmen that seems to be the case. I ran the program with strace and there is this call to mmap - mmap(NULL, 4294971392, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f243fa1f000. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Can't optimize them out; library calls are observable side effects.

Comment: @SouravGhosh ...and even if the compiler knows about `malloc` and `free` it can't be optimized out anyway because we use the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz right, without the `if` statement, in can be optimized out, I believe.

Comment: @MSalters not if we don;t use the return value. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: The returned pointer is used in the call to `free()` in any case, so I don't think it can be optimized out.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: You're wrong. Classical example would be `printf()` where the return value is commonly ignored.

Comment: @MSalters [can you sir please help me understand? thanks](https://godbolt.org/g/kSUJGI)

Comment: @MSalters _a gentle notification sir, comment will self-destruct...._

Comment: @SouravGhosh what you have shown in compiler explorer, that is with -O3 flag. Remove that flag and it will show call to malloc() function.

Comment: @Soumen Nice find!! However, the discussion was about optimization, so.... :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh what MSalters probably wants to express is a compiler can't optimize out a library call even if its return value is never used, because that call *could* have observable side-effects. I'd like to add: Even if the compiler knows the semantics of `malloc()` and can verify it links against the standard lib, with shared dynamic objects, someone could later exchange the library with a version that *does* have relevant side-effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard doesn't say anything about a heap, so, an implementation of `malloc()` is free to allocate memory in any suitable way. This could for example be from a fixed large buffer in a data segment on platforms that don't provide memory management.

In the case of `glibc`, `malloc` by default allocates memory using `mmap` if the requested chunk is sufficiently large. The traditional heap (through `sbrk`) is only used for smaller allocations.